# Javascript scroll vertically after clicking an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a set of buttons that are currently just images with different hover effects defined like so:

```
<img src="home.PNG" onmouseover="this.src='homemo.PNG'" onmouseout="this.src='home.PNG'" />
```

And what I want to do with them is scroll down to a different div upon clicking them but I am unsure on how to do this. I found a sample piece of code that works in this scenario here http://jsfiddle.net/ryXFt/3/ but my problem is that I don't know how to apply this to my images that I have created.

This is my failed attempt at trying to get it to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    <script>
    $("home.PNG").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".centre .main .para2").offset().top},
    'slow');
 });
    </script>
```

However it does not work and I am unsure simply how to get javascript to recognise the image as something to click.

Comment: home.PNG is not going to select anything - you can try $('img[src=home.PNG]') additionally, you don't need to animate both html and body

Comment: Read the jQuery documentation on selectors, this question indicates you haven't, use Stackoverflow after you've acquired the basics http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

your selector is wrong

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    <script>
    $("#myID").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".centre .main .para2").offset().top},
    'slow');
 });
    </script>
```

look at the jquery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Answer (score -1):

You need to add an id property to the image:

```
<img src='home.PNG' id='homeimg'.....>
```

And access it like this:

```
$("#homeimg").click(...
```